# Cannot align bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put the last div (processo div) align with the (tiposessao), but I want it at the next line, and I cant jump to the next line, even putting the row attribute. any solutions

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <label for="relator">Conselheiro Relator</label>
 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="relator" disabled="true" placeholder="Relator">
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tipo de Sessao <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Ordinaria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Especial</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
 </span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Data da Sessao"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <label for="processo" class="label-control"></label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
 </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please put your code on plunker so we will be able to troubleshoot easily..

Comment: where is `tiposessao` div or element ?

Comment: @jsantosh it is a button

Comment: @MiyuruRatnayake, i test there, but it doesnt stay the way I want because I need full screen

Comment: ok where is it (`tiposessao`) in OP ? and explain what you have and what you want t achieve and what you you tried .

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be what you are looking for as far as i understood.

https://jsfiddle.net/rnmdt2t8/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="processo" class="label-control"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Full code is on jsfiddle to check.